# How to correctly install Wine in 16.10?

Tags: wine, 16.10

I tried to install Wine-stable (1.8.5) in Yakkety using the official ppa: `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-wine/ppa` to no avail. The ppa doesn't seem valid and all i get is the old wine1.6. And it doesn't even show up in the main menu.

Is there another way to properly install it (1.8.5)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yakkety repository has wine 1.8.5 ([check here](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=yakkety&searchon=names&keywords=wine)), so no need to add a PPA.

Just install it using the command

```
sudo apt-get install wine
```

Comment: Thanks! It does install 1.8.5-ubuntu1, but there is no Wine submenu in the Main menu (Whisker menu). I need it to run some Windows software without any hassle. I installed Winetricks as well, but it doesn't let me install that specific software.

Comment: If you want to minimise hassle then you could try PlayOnLinux (`sudo apt install playonlinux`), do note that you can't make submissions to AppDB (to say how well certain programs work with Wine) if you use POL. Once you open POL it's reasonably self-explanatory how to install Windows programs.

Answer (score 5):

The correct command to install Wine-stable (1.8.5) is `sudo apt install wine-stable`. Just wine won't do. I hope it will help you.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Simply `sudo apt-get install wine` reports `Package 'wine' has no installation candidate`. You have to choose between `wine-stable` or `wine-development`

Answer (score 2):

A PPA is only built for versions of Ubuntu the PPA maintainer wants it built for.

In this case, you can see from [its page on Launchpad](https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-wine/+archive/ubuntu/ppa) that it's currently only built for versions of Ubuntu up to Xenial. I'm sure they'll add Yakkety in time, but PPAs lagging behind releases is perfectly normal.

Further, it seems fairly abandoned. I can't see an update this year. It's also not uncommon for PPAs to go through this lifecycle of adoption to "official unofficial repo"  and then die off to be replaced by another.

The PPA at [`ppa:wine/wine-builds`](https://launchpad.net/~wine/+archive/ubuntu/wine-builds) seems a lot healthier. It has Yakkety builds but these are the development and staging versions (which everybody playing any games is using because they have the latest and greatest <s>bugs</s> fixes).

But yes, if you're happy with [or require] 1.8.5, the main repo should keep you happy.